# Swift convert [String?] to [String!]

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I tested in **Swift 3.0**. I want to add `array1` to `array2`, example and errors as below:

```
var array1: [String?] = ["good", "bad"]
var array2 = [String!]()

array2.append(array1)
//Cannot convert value of type '[String?]' to expected argument type 'String!'
array2.append(contentsOf: array1)
//Extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:'in call
```

I know if I change to

```
var array2 = [String?]()
array2.append(contentsOf: array1)
```

it works! 
How should I fix this if i don't change type?

Comment: What about `array2.append(contentsOf: array1 as [String!])`?

Comment: Good example of misuse of implicit unwrapped optional. ;-)

Comment: Can you please explain exactly why you need array2 to be of type implicitly unwrapped Strings?

Comment: @SamM Actually i just want to try to see if it possible without any special reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>In Swift 3 you cannot define an array where the generic element is an implicitly unwrapped optional.</strike>

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are only allowed at top level and as function results.
>
> *The compiler*

What you can do is creating a new array of `String` containing only the populated elements of `array1`.

```
let array1: [String?] = ["good", "bad", nil]
let array2: [String] = array1.flatMap { $0 }

print(array2) // ["good", "bad"]
```

### Update

As shown by *Sam M* this is indeed possible, here's the code

```
let array2 = array1.map { elm -> String! in
    let res: String! = elm
    return res
}
```

Comment: May i ask what's `top level` here means?

Comment: If you can't define an array of implicitly unwrapped optionals how come this works? `var array = [String!]()`
        `array = ["1", "2"]`

Comment: @SamM: Very good point. This code does not compile `let array2: [String!] = [String!]()` but if you remove the definition of `array2` as you suggested it does work `let array2 = [String!]()`

Comment: @SamM: I updated my answer, thank you for you contribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array1: [String?] = ["good", "bad"]
var array2 = [String!]()
var array2a = [String]()

for item in array1 {
    array2.append(item)
}
for item in array1 {
    array2a.append(item!)
}
print("1", array1)
print("2", array2)
print("2a", array2a)
```

Prints:

1 [Optional("good"), Optional("bad")]

2 [good, bad]

2a ["good", "bad"]

Mapping also works, e.g.:

```
array2 = array1.map{ $0 }
array2a = array1.filter{ $0 != nil }.map{ $0! }
```